# Sinatra on Thin: How to hide or change HTTP 'Server' response header

Tags: sinatra, rack, thin

What is the cleanest way to do this? Some Rack middleware? I tried to modify `env['SERVER_SOFTWARE']` but I still get in response:

```
Server: thin 1.3.1 codename Triple Espresso
```

How to change the value of that header, or remove it completetly from response?

**EDIT**

Another try:

```
before do
  headers 'Server' => 'ipm'
end

after do
  headers 'Server' => 'ipm'
end
```

But still no changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works here:

```rb
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  [200, {'Server' => 'My Server'}, 'contents']
end
```

If you want to do it for all requests:

```rb
class ChangeServer
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    res = @app.call(env)
    res[1]['Server'] = 'My server'
    return res
  end
end
```

And then you `use ChangeServer` in your app.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But most of the routes return something like `json model_instance`. Adding hash of headers to each route is not the preferred solution.